# Customize CheckBox in DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, detailsview

I have a DetailsView that containing a CheckBoxField. The problem is that I want the check box to be changeable even in read only mode and in insert mode, it must be checked by default. How do I resolve this?

I attach a piece of code:

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="newsDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceNews"
                    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="id">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField FooterText="View at startpage" HeaderText="View" SortExpression="view">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="view" Checked='<%# Eval("view") %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                           <InsertItemTemplate>
                              <asp:CheckBox ID="viewInsert" Checked="true" runat="server" />
                           </InsertItemTemplate>
                           <EditItemTemplate>
                              <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="view" Checked='<%# Eval("view") %>' />
                           </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        ...
                        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" NewText="New" ButtonType="Button"
                            EditText="Edit" CancelText="Avbryt" DeleteText="Delete" InsertText="Add"
                            SelectText="Select" UpdateText="Uppdatera" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceNews" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newsConnectionString %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [nyheter] WHERE [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [nyheter] ([view], [headline], [post], [pic], [pic2]) VALUES (@view, @headline, @post, @pic, @pic2)"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [view], [date], [headline], [post], [pic], [pic2] FROM [nyheter] WHERE ([id] = @id)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [nyheter] SET [view] = @view, [headline] = @headline, [post] = @post, [pic] = @pic, [pic2] = @pic2  WHERE [id] = @id">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="newsList" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                    Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="view" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="headline" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="post" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pic3" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="view" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="headline" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="post" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="pic2" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that with the CheckBoxField, you have to create your own template for this field.

First, convert this field to a template field then you'll be able to control the templates  which will be CheckBoxes.

Then, you will find these CheckBoxes enabled in the insert and edit tempaltes and disabled in the ItemTmplate. You just need to enable it.

The code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="view" SortExpression="view">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="viewCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("view") %>' />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="viewCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("view") %>' 
            Enabled="true" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I understand that I must use a template, but have not managed to get it to work. I change the code to what I have done but that does not work

Comment: But how do I do so that the database change when I change the checkbox? And how do I do so that the checkbox is checked by default when insering?

Comment: @magol: You have to create your own CheckedChanged even handler for the CheckBox

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parameters and the sql statement are properly set adding DataField="yourField" to the Checkbox line will save the value of the check box to the database.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" DataField="yourField" runat="server" checked='<%# Bind("yourField")%>'></asp:CheckBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```